# Create empty date columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

Is there a way to add weekly date columns, filled with zeros, so that the df starts from January?

```
df
    2015-07-03    2015-07-10    2015-07-17
0      4             2            3
1      2             2            2
...
```

Expected Output

```
df
    2015-01-02   2015-01-09        ... 2015-07-03    2015-07-10   2015-03-17
0         0        0                      4            2             3
1         0        0                      2            2             2
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

Firstly create dates on weekly basis with `date_range()` method:

```
df.columns=pd.to_datetime(df.columns)    
date=pd.date_range('2015-01-02',df.columns.max(),freq='W')
```

Finally use `reindex()`,`append()` methods and Transpose(T) attribute :

```
result=df.T.reindex(date,fill_value=0).append(df.T).T
```

Now If you print `result` you will get your desired output

Comment: Great solution +1. You can skip the `fillna` and `astype` steps if you use the fill_value kwarg of reindex: `result = df.T.reindex(date, fill_value=0).append(df.T).T`

Comment: @HenryEcker Thank you for this information....Updated This in answer **:)**

Answer (score 1):

To determine dynamically the first day of the year, you can try:

```py
c = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
c = pd.date_range(
    "01-" + str(c.min().year),
    c.max(),
    freq="W-" + c.max().day_name()[:3].upper(),
)
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df = df.reindex(c, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   2015-01-02  2015-01-09  2015-01-16  2015-01-23  2015-01-30  2015-02-06  2015-02-13  2015-02-20  2015-02-27  2015-03-06  2015-03-13  2015-03-20  2015-03-27  2015-04-03  2015-04-10  2015-04-17  2015-04-24  2015-05-01  2015-05-08  2015-05-15  2015-05-22  2015-05-29  2015-06-05  2015-06-12  2015-06-19  2015-06-26  2015-07-03  2015-07-10  2015-07-17
0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           4           2           3
1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           2           2           2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves it for you.

```
start_date = '2015-01-02'
dti = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=weeks_number, freq="w")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = dti.date)
```

Just pass your desired weeks_number. You also may need to specify the day of the week, default is "W-SUN".